# Howto set QuillJS to plain text only

Tags: javascript, text-editor, rich-text-editor, html-editor, quill

Is there a way to set QuillJS to ony allow plaintext? Now we get every line in between DIV tags. I want ASCII with \r\n for linebreaks

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Uh... Use a `<textarea>` instead of Quill?

Comment: What's the use case? It does seem to be a tool + need mismatch.